Geojsonio does not render jsonfile
All,
The geojsonio package is not rendering simple JSON files on geojson.io as it should be. I get empty map as shown below

Here is the Python code I use to render the geojson file.
import geopandas as gpd
states = gpd.read_file('us-states.json') # available at https://github.com/PublicaMundi/MappingAPI/tree/master/data/geojson 
print(states.head())

states_ = states.to_json()
print(states_)

import geojsonio
geojsonio.display(states_)

However, I can render it by opening the json file via open tap https://geojson.io/#map=2/0/20 as shown below

Any ideas.
Thanks
